# Creating a comma separated string from an Object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Object from which i am trying to generate a comma separated string. Here is my code -

```
arrData = {
            "bl_number": "TCLPKGCTG1603200",
            "comodity": "GEN",
            "container": {
                           "container_id": "CRSU9007907",
                           "full_empty": true,
                           "type": 1
                         },
            "flc_lcl": "FCL",
            "weight": "25.0000"
          }

var row = "";

for (var index in arrData) {
    if(index == 'container'){
        for(var index_of_container_json in arrData[index]){
            if(index_of_container_json == 'container_id'){
                row = 'CONTAINER' + ',';
            }else if(index_of_container_json == 'full_empty'){
                row = 'F/E' + ',';
            }
        }
    }else if(index == 'bl_number'){
        row += 'B/L No' + ',';
    }else if(index == 'flc_lcl'){
        row += 'FCL/LCL' + ',';
    }else if(index == 'comodity'){
        row += 'COMMODITY' + ',';
    }else if(index == 'weight'){
        row += 'WGT' + ',';
    }
}
```

I am saving comma separated string in **row** variable. The final result is

```
F/E,B/L No,FCL/LCL,COMMODITY,WGT
```

My problem is, somehow **CONTAINER** is always going missing from **row**. I need my final result like this

```
CONTAINER,F/E,B/L No,FCL/LCL,COMMODITY,WGT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I see error here: `arrData = [.. ]` it should be `arrData = { ... }`
2. Exchange `row = ...` to `row += ...` everywhere

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.Since for loop in the object will iterate over properties one by one, hence the position of the CONTAINER in the result string will depend upon the position of the container property in the object arrData;

```
var arrData = {
            "bl_number": "TCLPKGCTG1603200",
            "comodity": "GEN",
            "container": {
                           "container_id": "CRSU9007907",
                           "full_empty": true,
                           "type": 1
                         },
            "flc_lcl": "FCL",
            "weight": "25.0000"
}

var row = "";
for (var index in arrData) {
    if(index == 'container'){
        for(var index_of_container_json in arrData[index]){
            if(index_of_container_json == 'container_id'){
                row += 'CONTAINER' + ',';
            }else if(index_of_container_json == 'full_empty'){
                row += 'F/E' + ',';
            }
        }
    }else if(index == 'bl_number'){
        row += 'B/L No' + ',';
    }else if(index == 'flc_lcl'){
        row += 'FCL/LCL' + ',';
    }else if(index == 'comodity'){
        row += 'COMMODITY' + ',';
    }else if(index == 'weight'){
        row += 'WGT' + ',';
    }
}

console.log(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
arrData = [{
  "bl_number": "TCLPKGCTG1603200",
  "comodity": "GEN",
  "container": {
    "container_id": "CRSU9007907",
    "full_empty": true,
    "type": 1
  },
  "flc_lcl": "FCL",
  "weight": "25.0000"
}]

var row = "";
for (i = 0; i < arrData.length; i += 1) {
  arrElem = arrData[i];
  row = "";
  for (var index in arrElem) {
    if (index == 'container') {
      str = '';
      for (var index_of_container_json in arrElem[index]) {
        if (index_of_container_json == 'container_id') {
          str += 'CONTAINER' + ',';
        } else if (index_of_container_json == 'full_empty') {
          str += 'F/E' + ',';
        }
      }
      row = str + row;
    } else if (index == 'bl_number') {
      row += 'B/L No' + ',';
    } else if (index == 'flc_lcl') {
      row += 'FCL/LCL' + ',';
    } else if (index == 'comodity') {
      row += 'COMMODITY' + ',';
    } else if (index == 'weight') {
      row += 'WGT' + ',';
    }
  }
  // remove the last comma.
  console.log(row.replace(/,\s*$/, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array and your array elements are objects.
You need to iterate throw your array elements properties too.

```
arrData.forEach(function(value){
         for(var index in value){
            if(index == 'container'){
                for(var index_of_container_json in arrData[index]){
                    if(index_of_container_json == 'container_id'){
                        row = 'CONTAINER' + ',';
                    }else if(index_of_container_json == 'full_empty'){
                        row = 'F/E' + ',';
                    }
                }
           }else if(index == 'bl_number'){
                row += 'B/L No' + ',';
           }else if(index == 'flc_lcl'){
                row += 'FCL/LCL' + ',';
           }else if(index == 'comodity'){
                row += 'COMMODITY' + ',';
           }else if(index == 'weight'){
                row += 'WGT' + ',';
           }
      }
  }
```

Comment: he/she just edited his question and my answer make no sense in this moment!